# How to Push Data to dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I am trying to push data to a `history` array that will be updated inside a `dom-repeat` template.

**Template**

```
<paper-button on-tap="_addToHistory">Add to History</paper-button>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{history}}">
  <h3 class="test">[[item.name]]</h3>
</template>
```

**Properties**

```
history: {
  type: Array,
  value: []
}
```

**Functions**

```
_addToHistory() {
  this.history.push({"name": "Computer"});
}
```

When I log out history I see an array of objects, but nothing is appended to the dom when `_addToHistory` is called.

*How can I setup a* `dom-repeat` *template to respond to an object updating?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.push('history', {"item"})` to notify the template to update with fresh data.